# procedimiento almacenado con parámetros dinámicos

Tags: sql, laravel, sql-server, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en sql server:

```html
BEGIN
 IF (@canal = '')     BEGIN SET @canal= '%'      END  
 IF (@cadenaventa = '0')    BEGIN SET @cadenaventa= '%'    END 
 IF (@grupomall ='0')     BEGIN SET @grupomall= '%'    END 
 IF (@mall = '0')      BEGIN SET @mall= '%'     END 
 IF (@clase = '0')      BEGIN SET @clase = '%'     END
 IF (@familia = '0')      BEGIN SET @familia= '%'     END
 IF (@marca = '0')      BEGIN SET @marca= '%'     END 
 IF (@coleccion ='0')        BEGIN SET @coleccion= '%'    END 
 IF (@val_almacenes = '')    BEGIN SET @val_almacenes= '%'   END 

 IF((@cargo = '%') and (@nacionalidad = '%') and (@clase = '%') and (@familia = '%') and (@marca ='%') and (@coleccion = '%') ) 
 
 BEGIN 
  -- EL UNICO FILTRO SON LAS FECHAS O LA VARIABLE DE SESION DE ALMACENES
  PRINT 'entra en el 1'
  PRINT @fecha_anual 
  SELECT distinct(al.id_almacen), al.des_almacen, al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, 
   SUM(T1.preciolista_ytd) as precio_ytd, 
   CASE WHEN @fecha_anual = 1 THEN 
    SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ac) 
   ELSE 
    CASE WHEN @fecha_anual = 2 THEN 
     SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ar)  
    ELSE
     CASE WHEN @fecha_anual = 3 THEN 
      SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ac/i2.val_indipc)
     ELSE 
      SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ar/i2.val_indipc)
     END
    END 
   END AS precio_yld
        FROM dim.almacen as al
            LEFT JOIN fact.venta_comparada_empleado_producto as T1 ON T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dim.indipc i2 ON i2.id_calendario = (T1.id_calendario - 10000) 
        WHERE (T1.id_calendario >= @fechaini and T1.id_calendario <= @fechafin )  
          AND al.canalventa like @canal 
    AND al.cadenaventa like @cadenaventa
    AND al.grupomall like @grupomall 
    AND al.des_almacen like @mall 
    AND al.cod_almacen LIKE (@val_almacenes)
        GROUP BY al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, al.id_almacen, al.des_almacen  
        ORDER BY al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, al.des_almacen
  END
  END
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlo mas "eficiente", que se ejecute mas rápido, porque además necesito agregar el manejo de stock que viene dado por otro store procedure y ya de por si, el stock, consume mucho tiempo y la aplicación de laravel desde la cual estoy consultando éstos datos, se termina "cayendo" o dando un error 504.

El stock viene dado por:

```html
(SELECT id_almacen, sum(stock) as stock 
   FROM 
   (SELECT id_almacen, sum(stock) as stock FROM fact.stock_acumulado 
    WHERE  id_calendario = @fechainicio  
    AND  id_almacen =  @id_almacen 
    group by id_almacen 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT id_almacen, sum(stock) as stock FROM fact.stock_acumulado_diario 
    WHERE  id_calendario = @fechafin  
    AND  id_almacen =  @id_almacen  
    group by id_almacen 
   ) T1 

   group by id_almacen 
   having sum(stock) > 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones para realizarlo. La sencilla es agregando `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` al final de la consulta. Esa cláusula genera que se recompile la instrucción en cada ejecución y el motor de SQL Server pueda usar un plan óptimo en vez de un plan seguro.

La otra opción es mi favorita y consiste en usar código dinámico para especificar únicamente los filtros que vayamos a utilizar.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Condiciones NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
            @SQL         NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    IF (@canal <> '')
        SET @Condiciones += N'AND al.canalventa LIKE @canal ' + NCHAR(13) 

    IF (@cadenaventa <> '0')
        SET @Condiciones += N'AND al.cadenaventa LIKE @cadenaventa ' + NCHAR(13) 

    IF (@grupomall <> '0')
        SET @Condiciones += N'AND al.grupomall LIKE @grupomall ' + NCHAR(13) 

    IF (@mall <> '0')
        SET @Condiciones += N'AND al.des_almacen LIKE @mall ' + NCHAR(13) 

    IF (@val_almacenes <> '')
        SET @Condiciones += N'AND al.cod_almacen LIKE (@val_almacenes) ' + NCHAR(13) 

    IF (@clase = '0')
        SET @clase = '%'

    IF (@familia = '0')
        SET @familia = '%'

    IF (@marca = '0')
        SET @marca = '%'

    IF (@coleccion = '0')
        SET @coleccion = '%'

    IF (
            (@cargo = '%')
            AND (@nacionalidad = '%')
            AND (@clase = '%')
            AND (@familia = '%')
            AND (@marca = '%')
            AND (@coleccion = '%')
            )
    BEGIN
        -- EL UNICO FILTRO SON LAS FECHAS O LA VARIABLE DE SESION DE ALMACENES
        PRINT 'entra en el 1'
        --PRINT @fecha_anual
        SET  @SQL = 
          N'SELECT al.id_almacen,                                                                  ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.des_almacen,                                                                    ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.canalventa,                                                                     ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.cadenaventa,                                                                    ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    SUM(T1.preciolista_ytd) AS precio_ytd,                                             ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    CASE WHEN @fecha_anual = 1                                                         ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'            THEN SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ac)                                            ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        WHEN @fecha_anual = 2                                                          ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'            THEN SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ar)                                            ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        WHEN @fecha_anual = 3                                                          ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'            THEN SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ac / i2.val_indipc)                            ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        ELSE SUM(T1.preciolista_yld_ar / i2.val_indipc)                                ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    END AS precio_yld                                                                  ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'FROM dim.almacen AS al                                                                 ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'LEFT JOIN fact.venta_comparada_empleado_producto AS T1 ON T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'LEFT OUTER JOIN dim.indipc i2 ON i2.id_calendario = (T1.id_calendario - 10000)         ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'WHERE (                                                                                ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        T1.id_calendario >= @fechaini                                                  ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        AND T1.id_calendario <= @fechafin                                              ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'        )                                                                              ' + NCHAR(13)
        + @Condiciones
        + N'GROUP BY al.canalventa,                                                                ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.cadenaventa,                                                                    ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.id_almacen,                                                                     ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.des_almacen                                                                     ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'ORDER BY al.canalventa,                                                                ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.cadenaventa,                                                                    ' + NCHAR(13)
        + N'    al.des_almacen; '
    END
    PRINT @SQL;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
                       N'@fechaini       datetime,
                         @fechafin       datetime,
                         @canal          varchar(100),
                         @cadenaventa    varchar(100),
                         @grupomall      varchar(100),
                         @mall           varchar(100),
                         @val_almacenes  varchar(100)',
                       @fechaini     , 
                       @fechafin     , 
                       @canal        , 
                       @cadenaventa  , 
                       @grupomall    , 
                       @mall         , 
                       @val_almacenes;
END
```

El usar código dinámico permite que reutilizar planes de ejecución compilados, así podemos tener un poco de ventajas de ambos mundos. Además, escribiendo el código de una forma legible, podemos darle mantenimiento de una forma tan sencilla como si fuera código estático. Además, se puede parametrizar para evitar problemas con inyección de SQL.